# Android 8 RIL socket is missing?

Tags: android, ril

I have been researching about ril and I have noticed in Android 8 ril socket is missing.

1. `rild` socket is missing in `/dev/socket/`. Did it move any where else ?

I see a new folder called `qmux_radio` and inside (on Nexus 5X)

```
srw-rw---- 1 radio radio 0 2018-02-23 09:51 qmux_connect_socket

srwx------ 1 radio radio 0 2018-02-23 11:54 rild_ims0

srwx------ 1 radio radio 0 2018-02-23 11:54 rild_oem0

srwx------ 1 radio radio 0 2018-02-23 11:54 uim_remote_client_socket

srwx------ 1 radio radio 0 2018-02-23 11:54 uim_remote_server_socket
```

these seems to be related to vendor (QMI - Qualcomm Linux Modems)

2. How's com.android.phone process talk to rild in Android 8

Android documentation related to RIL seems to be out-of-date as of now

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not missing. It has been move to `/vendor/bin/hw/rild` in newer versions of Android. sorry for the late response.